# version upgrade from wso2am-3.2.0 to wso2am 4.1.0

Tags: token, port

Am using wso2 am 4.1.0 version am not able to generate access token by http://localhost:8280/auth/token   it will be get by https://localhost:9444/oauth2/token

[getting response from this wso2 is url [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AYa3.png)

not getting response from gateway port url
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs5Wt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Token and Revoke endpoints have been removed from the Gateway artifacts from API-M 4.0.0 onwards. Hence you need to use Key Manager to generate the tokens.
Please refer to the [document](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/get-started/about-this-release/#what-has-changed).